# Execute Setup with admin rights

Tags: c#, winforms, operating-system, setup-project

I have a windows forms app developed in c# and have created a setup file for it. 
.Net Framework used is 3.0.

Now, setup should force for admin rights for installation and then proceed else not.

I found articles on creating manifest file which works fine but when program is launched after installation it again asks for admin rights which is not i want.

And this prompt should also work on Windows XP SP 1 and above OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I force my .NET application to run as administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator)

Comment: @Clint - Actually i don't want to run GUI application with admin rights. But if admin allows to install the app then app should get installed and hence while installing setup we want to prompt for admin rights.

Comment: @Ronak, while installing any MSI/WindowsInstaller will prompt for admin rights, the setup file is nothing but a collection of assemblies,dlls,files, you're app needs to function. But after installation is your GUI app performing tasks that require elevated privilege ?

Comment: @SMMahmudulHasan - Will app.manifest file work for Windows XP as well? I mean Windows XP and later OS.

Comment: @Ronak is your question about enabling setup file to throw UAC prompt ?

Comment: @Clint - Yes excatly, setup file should prompt. So that only admin user can install the app.

Comment: 1) Right Click your Setup Project, View->Launch Conditions.

2) Right click on Launch Conditions, and add a new Condition in your Launch Conditions.

3) Right click the Condition, choose Properties Window.

4) Set Condition to AdminUser.

5) Build and install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To prompt Installer to invoke the UAC prompt to the user you can do the following:*

- Right click your Setup Project > View > Launch Conditions.
- Right click Launch Conditions > Add a new Condition in your Launch Conditions.
- Right click the Condition, choose Properties Window.
- Set Condition to [AdminUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/adminuser?redirectedfrom=MSDN). (You can also try setting [Privileged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/privileged?redirectedfrom=MSDN) property)
- Build and install

**OR**

*Edit your .vdproj, change requiresElevation attribute to `true`*

```
"MsiBootstrapper"
{

    "RequiresElevation" = "11:TRUE"
}
```

Comment: I will try solution provided by you. I also found another way by adding app.manifest file and setting requestedExecutionLevel to requireAdministrator like below. 
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />

Comment: yes, you are doing the above on your WinForm project or Installer Project ?

Comment: It is in win forms project.

Comment: yes you can do that on winforms project, then your winforms app will throw the UAC prompt, instead of the Installer.

Comment: @Ronak, you can let me know if you need help

Comment: @Ronak, you're welcome, if you think the answer has helped out, you can accept the answer by clicking the green tick mark ;)